# How to show a PHP page (with HTML) in another PHP Page (with HTML)

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, merge, embed

I work on PHP Script and I try to merge it with another file upload ccript I was made before (PHP & HTML Page)
I don't want to make another PHP page and include the old script it, I want the file upload script in the same page of my new script (same file).
I try the  method but I only get errors.
And I try every method I found but none.

The idea simply is:

My Current PHP Page:

```
<?php
<html>
<body>
    <!-- here I want the Page 2 in a specific area ( It's responsive ) -->
</body>
</html>
?>
```

exactly like:

[image]

Thank you PROs.

Answer (score 0):

When you include a PHP file in another, everything in that file are copied to second one.

for example:

p1.php:

```
<?php
echo "hello ";
?>
```

p2.php:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
include "p1.php":
?>
world
</body>
<html>
```

output of p2.php will be:

> hello world

now if you want to use some php scripts you already have, It is recommended to save them as PHP file, completely separated from codes that handle view, and use them anywhere you want. It is better if you make them Class file.

Comment: Thank you.
my problem is to make the php page showing in another php page in the html content:
please take a look: i.imgur.com/OyhXxdz.png

Comment: you use `include` but the DOM structure would have errors. if you insist on including another php file in another, maybe using an `iframe` can help you. `<iframe src="p2.php"></iframe>`

Comment: no bro my problem is about making this:

http://i.stack.imgur.com/AsKR4.png

Answer (score 0):

Open the php page where you want to show the another php page and add

```
<?php include: 'page.php'; ?>
```

Note: you cannot write html like this

```
<?php <html> </html> ?> this is wrong
```

To add the another php page write code like this below

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>Welcome to my home page!</h1>
<p>Some text.</p>
<p>Some more text.</p>
<?php include 'footer.php';?>

</body>
</html>
```

and save it as name.php

Answer (score -1):

you can use query for add a second page into a div,
using this technique you can append one or more pages into a specific div

```
<?php

    <!--HERE WILL BE ADDED THE SECOND PAGE -->
    <div id ="content"></div>

    <script>
       $(document).ready( function() {
            $("#content").load("content.php"); //NAME OF THE PAGE TO ADD
       });
    </script>


?>
```

Answer (score -1):

use iframe to include te ather page

```
 <iframe src="demo_iframe.htm" width="200" height="200"></iframe>
```

or in php use

```
 ob_start(); 
 require $action;
 $content_for_layout = ob_get_clean();
```

and echo

```
 $content for layout
```

or visit [php layout](http://zrclassroom.com/toturials/creation-d-un-espace-membre-php-mysql-partie-4-la-structure-php-du-site--221)